# Information about a Game Gallery box by a company called Swing! Entertainment

Tags: pc

Today I got this sealed box of games from flee market. Does anyone know anything about this company or the value of this box? The company is called Swing! Entertainment, the box is from 1998.

[image: Picture of the box]

Comment: @wrigglenite May I ask what search terms you used? I did a bit of googling myself and the only relevent result was this question.

Comment: @Studoku Surprisingly enough, "Swing Entertainment Media" gets me many results, and this question isn't even on the first page.

Answer (score 4):

Swing Entertainment Media AG was a producer and publisher of video games until its bankruptcy in 2003. The company was founded in 1998 and started with second and third marketing of PC games (like your Game Gallery). Later on they also produced new games and ported games to consoles.  [[Source (in German)]](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_Entertainment_Media)